# What is the best way to tune LINQ with pagination and order by?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a nullable column in my SQL Server table, let's say `SomeDate`. My objective is to get the rows where `SomeDate` is not null, then order by that same column and use pagination.

Here are sample rows:

```
SomeDate
----------------------------------
2023-08-28 07:00:00.0000000 +00:00
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2023-09-11 07:00:00.0000000 +00:00
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Desired result:

```
2023-08-28 07:00:00.0000000 +00:00
2023-09-11 07:00:00.0000000 +00:00
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
...
```

Now, I can achieve this by using the following query. Per my understanding, `OrderByDescending` will be expensive but does return the desired result:

```
query.OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeDate.HasValue)
      .ThenBy(x => x.SomeDate)
      .Skip(skip) // skip=0
      .Take(take) // take=10
      .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

If I use following then, first will fetch 10 records then do ordering which will be quick but doesn't return the desired result:

```
query.Skip(skip) // skip=0
     .Take(take) // take=10
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeDate.HasValue)
     .ThenBy(x => x.SomeDate)
     .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

Result:

```
2023-08-28 07:00:00.0000000 +00:00
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Question:

- How efficient will the query that returns the desired results be on large data sets (i.e., >= 100K rows)?
- If it is (too) expensive, then what is the best approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Without trying, I think it should be faster to use `Where` rather than `OrderByDescending`:   `.Where(x=>x.SomeDate!=null).OrderBy...`

Comment: Do you or do you not want records that are null? It's a bit unclear cause your examples don't match your text *get the records where SomeDate is not null*

Comment: Pagination before ordering is incorrect anyway (you're just ordering an indeterminate  slice of data), so that's not even an option. Further, ordering != filtering. Ordering can never guarantee that you "get the rows where `SomeDate` is not null". (Think of the extreme case where such rows don't exist). Finally "If it is (too) expensive" -- first establish whether it is.

Comment: @siggemannen sorry for confusion. I want both but first get the data with value, then sort it, then get null values.

Comment: The default DateTime object is 1/1/01 (not null).  The easiest way is to replace the Null with "new DateTime()".  The the sort will correctly work.

Comment: You want KeySet Pagination, this is by far the most efficient paging method. The linked answer shows how to do it in SQL, it shouldn't be difficult to convert for LINQ. You need an index on `SomeDate`, and then you just need to keep track of the last `SomeDate` recieved, and page forward from there. `OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeDate)` would normally take into account nulls, you don't need the `ThenBy` separately.

Comment: not sure keyset pagination will work well with null values